# PHP5 integration with iCal and Outlook

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I have searched something where I can integrate iCal and Outlook from my PHP5 calendar system, can somebody help me to get more infomation?

And is it possible to auto sync my system and iCal and Outlook if the customer wants to add new events from Outlook or iCal?

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help: http://sabre.io/dav/ (a caldav server for php)